# Vaadin error : com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'

Tags: java, sql-server, vaadin7

I'm trying a sample with Vaadin + Sql Server.

After create a JDBCConnectionPool I have the following :

```
TableQuery tq = new TableQuery("myTableName", MyJDBCConnectionPool);
tq.setVersionColumn("MyIdColName");
SQLContainer container = new SQLContainer(tq);
```

Then I got this error :

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'
```

Any help please ?

Answer (score 4):

I guess this isn't Vaadin-related: it seems to me that the problem is that JDBC thinks it's talking to a MySQL database (LIMIT is a MySQL reserved word); you need to re-check your configuration (about which I can't be of help, but if you post it others could review it).

Comment: Agree but, the only difference between a Sql Server JDBC connection and a MySQL one to create a Pool is the driver name.

Comment: Can you post how you initialize that *MyJDBCConnectionPool* object?

Comment: Shure : 
JDBCConnectionPool conn =   new SimpleJDBCConnectionPool(
"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
"jdbc:sqlserver://MyServerName\\SQL2012;databaseName=MyDbName;",      "MyUserName", "MyPass");
TableQuery tq = new TableQuery("products_table", conn);
tq.setVersionColumn("product_ID");
SQLContainer container = new SQLContainer(tq);

Answer (score 3):

You should use MSSQLGenerator instead of DefaultSQLGenerator.
DefaultSQLGenerator uses the LIMIT clause and not MSSQLGenerator.